# JavaFX 8 Double binding one way validation

Tags: binding, javafx

In my app a TextField is bound bi-directionally to a pane's layoutXProperty. Any changes in the textfield will update the layoutX of the pane immediately.

For example if layoutX is 500 and the last zero is deleted, the pane's position jumps immediatley to x = 50. Equally if the pane is dragged around the value in the texfield reflects the layoutX value of the pane.

The 'dragging' binding is fine, but now I want to wait for the RETURN key in the textfield before the pane's layoutX is updated (I want to check for valid boundary values first). I have tried ChangeListeners and low-level binding, but cannot get it to work satisfactorily.

Does any one have any ideas about how to implement this. It seems to me that this would be a common action, but there is VERY little info in either books or on the web about this. Can a changelistener 'consume a binding event'?

Comment: Just use two listeners instead of bindings. Use a listener for an `ActionEvent` on the `TextField`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a listener to the `layoutX` property that updates the text field, and add a handler for an action event to the `TextField` that performs the validation and updates the `layoutX` property. The handler will get fired if the user presses Enter, but not before. Since you don't want `layoutX` to get updated any time the text is updated, a binding is not really appropriate here.

SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PaneCoordinatesInTextField extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label draggingLabel = createDraggingLabel();

        TextField textField = new TextField();
        draggingLabel.layoutXProperty().addListener((obs, oldLayoutX, newLayoutX) ->
            textField.setText(newLayoutX.toString()));

        textField.setOnAction(e -> {
            try {
                double x = Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());
                if (x < 0) {
                     x = 0 ;
                }
                if (x > 400) {
                    x = 400 ;
                }
                draggingLabel.setLayoutX(x);
            } catch (NumberFormatException exc) {
                textField.setText(Double.toString(draggingLabel.getLayoutX()));
            }
        });

        Pane pane = new Pane(draggingLabel);
        pane.setMinSize(600, 600);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(pane, textField, null, null, null);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Label createDraggingLabel() {
        Label label = new Label("Drag me", new Rectangle(200, 200, Color.CORNFLOWERBLUE));
        label.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.CENTER);
        label.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);
        label.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        ObjectProperty<Point2D> mouseLocation = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        label.setOnDragDetected(e -> mouseLocation.set(new Point2D(e.getSceneX(), e.getSceneY())));
        label.setOnMouseReleased(e -> mouseLocation.set(null));
        label.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            if (mouseLocation.get() == null) {
                return ;
            }
            double deltaX = e.getSceneX() - mouseLocation.get().getX();
            double deltaY = e.getSceneY() - mouseLocation.get().getY();
            label.setLayoutX(label.getLayoutX() + deltaX);
            label.setLayoutY(label.getLayoutY() + deltaY);
            mouseLocation.set(new Point2D(e.getSceneX(), e.getSceneY()));
        });
        return label;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the sort of example that other people may find very helpful when looking for a similar solution - so well done for posting a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

I have found 'a' solution, but it seems more like a kludge.

I attached an onMouseClicked and an onActon handler to the textfield.

In the textfield onMouseClicked I unbind the textfield and wait for the RETURN key to be pressed. In the onAction I update the previously bound value with the new textfield value and then bind it bi-directionally again. And voila... it works.

I can check for valid values in the onAction handler.

But like I said it seems a bit of bandaid solution. Anyone care to comment?

Comment: Yeah I sort of got there myself. I still like the single binding concept (for consistency with other fields), so I'll keep the 'dragging update' binding but ditch the other one in favour of a listener for an  Action handler.

Comment: If you don't want it to change whenever the text changes, a binding is not what you want. Just use the listeners to update the values directly.